# select box not retaining value in AJAX call

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the option value of a select and I don't know why but it's not working. I'm attempting to set it inside of the success function of an AJAX call. Is this not possible?

Here is what I am using to set the option value:

```
$.ajax({...
    success:function(data){
      if(data.value == 0){
        $.post("/theme",{theme:theme});
        $("#themes").val(theme); // Dropdown box
      }else{
        $("#themes").val(data.theme); // Dropdown box
      }
    }
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you set `theme` (as opposed to `data.theme`)?

Comment: Above the ajax call. I can `alert` the value just fine so I know it's there.

Comment: Are you sure that your `<option>` tags have a `val` attribute that corresponds to `theme` and `data.theme`?

Comment: What @max_w said.Try selecting and see what <code>$('#themes option[value="'+theme+'"]')</code> returns you. Maybe there's a typo in the response or the value doesn't exist. Could be a tone of things.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I've looked at it several times. Thanks for having a look

Comment: @Ancarius, thanks. I'll do that now.

Comment: OK, it's echoing the correct values back in the javascript file but the select isn't showing that value for some reason.

Comment: I figured it out with your guys' help! It seems that there is a plugin that is screwing things up. When I get rid of the plugin, I can see the right value. So, I'll have to work on this a little more to see why it's doing what it's doing. Thanks again for putting me on the right track, guys!

Comment: Glad to hear. Good luck!